# Convert string time into date swift

Tags: swift

I have json from rest API :

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "query": {
    "format": "json",
    "kota": "703",
    "tanggal": "2017-02-07"
  },
  "jadwal": {
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
      "ashar": "15:26",
      "dhuha": "06:21",
      "dzuhur": "12:10",
      "imsak": "04:28",
      "isya": "19:31",
      "maghrib": "18:20",
      "subuh": "04:38",
      "tanggal": "Selasa, 07 Feb 2017",
      "terbit": "05:54"
    }
  }
}
```

I want convert jadwal -> data -> ashar and other into Date format
**I have this code,**

```
extension String {
    func convertToDate() -> Date? {
        let arr = self.split(separator: ":")
        guard
            let hour = Int(arr.first ?? ""),
            let minute = Int(arr.last ?? "")
        else { return nil }
        
        let component = DateComponents(hour: hour, minute: minute)
        var cal = Calendar.current
        guard let timezone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Jakarta") else { return nil }
        cal.timeZone = timezone
        let date = cal.date(from: component)
        return date
    }
}
```

But i get this result on my console debug

```
ashar: 0001-01-01 08:27:48 +0000
```

i expect for example on asr/ashar = **2021-01-12 15:26:00** for Indonesia Time, do you guys have advice or something?

Comment: Please point out what you mean by 'working well'.  Also, please post what you get and what you're expecting.

Comment: i have edited, pls check again @ewong

Comment: You *expect* the date to be today so the dates in the JSON are irrelevant?

Comment: date of json just a dummy json, in productionn it must be 2021-01-12, and date on json, is not used in my code @vadian

Comment: Are you aware that printing a date object will display it in the UTC time zone (hence +0000 at the end)? To get it printed in the local time zone use `print(date.description(with: .current))`

Comment: correct, i missed it @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an extension for string that returns a full date object by passing only the time string as follows.

```swift
extension String {
    func createDateObjectWithTime(format: String = "HH:mm") -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        guard let dateObjectWithTime = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else { return nil }
        
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let now = Date()
        let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        var dateComponents = gregorian.dateComponents(components, from: now)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        dateComponents.hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: dateObjectWithTime)
        dateComponents.minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: dateObjectWithTime)
        dateComponents.second = 0

        return gregorian.date(from: dateComponents)
    }
}
```

You can call the extension by:

```
let date = "15:26".createDateObjectWithTime()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just get the current date and set hour and minute to the extracted values

```
extension String {
    func convertToDate() -> Date? {
        let arr = self.split(separator: ":")
        guard
            let hour = Int(arr.first ?? ""),
            let minute = Int(arr.last ?? "")
        else { return nil }
        
        var cal = Calendar.current
        guard let timezone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Jakarta") else { return nil }
        cal.timeZone = timezone
        return cal.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute, second: 0, of: Date())
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this result ashar: 2021-01-12 08:35:00 the date is correct, but not for the time @vadian